# loop until user enters one of three required letters

Tags: powershell, do-while

Currently I have this:

```
do {
  $MAB = Read-Host "Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment? (M)andatory, (A)dvertised, (B)oth"
} while ($MAB -ne "M","A","B")
```

But it isn't working for me.

What I need it to do is request the user if they want an Advertised, Mandatory or Both, and depending on what they need they type in M for Mandatory, A for Advertised or B for Both.

At the moment, using what I have above if I put in any of the 3 letters it just asks again.

If I set it up like this though:

```
do {
  $MAB = Read-Host "Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment? (M)andatory, (A)dvertised, (B)oth"
} while ($MAB -ne "M")
```

It works fine, although that doesn't help me for the A or B inputs.

Also if you could explain how I can throw an error saying "You must enter either A for Advertised, B for Both, or M for Mandatory, to proceed." If they put in anything other than a M, A, or B.

Comment: `$Host.UI.PromptForChoice('','Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment?',('&Mandatory','&Advertised','&Both'),-1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found it out - I have been looking all day for this and it was quite hard to find the answer for multiples.

It's not actually a `do..while`, it's a `do..until`:

```
do {
  $MAB = Read-Host "Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment? (M)andatory, (A)dvertised, (B)oth"
} until (($MAB -eq "M") -or ($MAB -eq "A") -or ($MAB -eq "B"))
```

I hope this helps someone else out there.

Comment: `$MAB -in 'M','A','B'` or `'M','A','B' -contains $MAB`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$title = "Deployment choices"
$message = "Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment?"

$mandatory = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Mandatory"
$advertised = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Advertised"
$both = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Both"
$options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($mandatory, $advertised, $both)

#do
#{
    $result = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options, 0) 

    switch ($result)
    {
        0 {"You selected Mandatory."}
        1 {"You selected Advertised."}
        2 {"You selected Both." }
    }
#}
#until ($result -in 0..2)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't require a loop, because the method will continue prompting until it receives one of the allowed responses (or `Enter`, which will select the default response).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Commented-out the loop but kept it in source so that your comment stays meaningful.

Comment: The `PromptForChoice` API is useful - I just wish there was a more succinct way to use it from PowerShell scripts. Is there really no built-in cmdlet for presenting choices to the user?

Comment: Found several solutions how to interact with user inputs. This is the only one, which is not using a loop and is even working! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

I think this is fairly neat:

```
do {
  $MAB = Read-Host "Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment? (M)andatory, (A)dvertised, (B)oth"
} until ($("M","A","B").Contains($MAB))
```

Comment: @PetSerAl - Yes, that's correct. The question only asks for uppercase entry.

Comment: @PetSerAl I have tested and it accepts both upper and lowercase entry.

Comment: @Random206 I just test and `$("M","A","B").Contains("a")` return `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is the [`choice`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732504.aspx) command:

```
choice /c mab /m 'Do you require a Mandatory and/or Advertised deployment'
switch ($LASTEXITCODE) {
  1 { 'You selected Mandatory.' }
  2 { 'You selected Advertised.' }
  3 { 'You selected Both.' }
}
```